# Retrieving JSON on server (NodeJs), but keep getting "Unexpected Token U in position 0"

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, node.js

So I've read a bunch of the other posts about sending and retrieving `JSON` with `NodeJs` and `Express`, but I can't seem to get this to work. Somebody said it was because the `JSON` is invalid.

```
var arr = { City: 'someplace', Country:Australia};

$.ajax({
    url: '/profile_upload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log("THE THING SHOULD've WORKED! " + msg);
    }
});
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
server.post('/profile_upload', function(req, res){
  var value = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log("the data sent is: " + value.city);

});
```

The console is not logging the city at all, just crashing at the error. I'm using jquery 3.1.1.

Comment: console the request you are getting and also parsed version of request and share it with us so that we can be sure you are getting it in request properly

Comment: I am getting an undefined when console.logging from the server side "req.body". I still dont know what the solution is...

Answer (score 1):

Barring the possibility that `Australia` has been defined elsewhere as a variable, I'm going to assume that it should be a string; accordingly, you should put quotes around it:

```
var arr = { City: "someplace", Country: "Australia" };
```

Single or double, doesn't matter.

UPDATE:

Next, you shouldn't need to parse the request body. I did a quick test with Express on the server side, and the following code is working:

```
router.post('/profile_upload', (req, res, next) => {
  const value = req.body;
  console.log("the data sent is: " + value.City);
  res.status(200).send({ message: "Success!" });
});
```

The server should automatically parse the incoming string into a JS object. I also noticed that in your original code, the key for `City` is capitalized in the object you sent in your request, but you didn't capitalize it in your route.

For reference, here's my client side code (that works):

```
var arr = { City: "someplace", Country: "Australia" }

$.ajax({
  url: '/profile_upload',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(arr),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  error: function (err) {
    console.log('oh no:', err);
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('message:', data.message);
  }
});
```

Note that because you've indicated `dataType` will be JSON, the response received will automatically be parsed into a JS object.

Comment: I changed the country value to a string by putting quotes around it, but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Lifeislifebutwhatiswhat I've updated my answer with working code. Give it a whirl and see if it works for you.